# Getting hexadecimal character escape while printing string in Xcode

Tags: string, c++11, hex, xcode8, macos-sierra

I'm trying to run this C++ code in Xcode 8.1:

```
  std::string str = "g[+g]g[-g]g[−g[+g]g]g[+g]g";
  for (auto& c : str) {
      printf("%c", c);
  }
```

and I'm getting this as output:

> g[+g]g[-g]g[\342\210\222g[+g]g]g[+g]g

Does anyone knows why some characters are coming as hexadecimal characters?

I already tried to print as c_str().

Comment: One of the minus signs isn't one.

Comment: actually, some characters are coming as *octal* character representation, not hexadecimal :-)